# Trying to introduce Unit Testing to a project, but .pch file missing

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

I'm trying to introduce Unit Testing to a project. The project compiles, builds, runs perfectly fine.

However, when I try to run Test, I get a failed compile error that a .pch file is missing.

I've cleaned the project, cleaned the build folder, and deleted the derived data before trying both those steps again. But every time, it fails with a no-such-file-or-directory /blah/blah/ProjectName-Prefix.pch error.

Any thoughts as to how I can stop it looking for something that doesn't exist? Or alternatively, make the file exist so that it can be found?

Comment: Goto Build Settings and search for "Prefix Header" and fix/delete the reference?

Comment: Thanks, that's solved that problem. It's now crapping out on a different file-not-found linker error, this time one that doesn't show up when I search. :(

Comment: The problem was that the project had been renamed at an earlier date.

Searching the Build Settings for oldname and updating them all to newname means that it's now looking for them in the correct places.

(Apparently I can't answer my own question for another 8 hours...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the project had been renamed at an earlier date.

Searching the Build Settings for oldname and updating them all to newname means that it's now looking for the files in the correct places.